# Setup service to run software

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, sudo

I have a problem with launching an application like a service. I need to set up this application to startup with ubuntu and I decided to make a service. I can run this application via terminal using sudo and it works fine. But service doesn't start fully. In logs I can see: `SysDirRead_[188]: stat(var/run/user/1000//gvfs):Permission denied`. I think that application can't start all components because it doesn't have rights.
Below service conf file. I tested `User and Group = root`.

```
[Unit]
Description=custom service
After=network.target
[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
ExecStart=path/application.bin path/conf_file.conf
# Output to syslog
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
#Change this to find app logs in /var/log/syslog
SyslogIdentifier=vplc
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

gvfs is a FUSE mount point. As FUSE file systems are not implemented by kernel code, root does not automatically have access. That is up to the FUSE application to decide.

If the application does not need root privilege then it may help to have it run under the UID 1000.